# Remove div and table from td element using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a file named 'ahblog.htm' and inside this file contains a 'td element'. I am using 'jquery' to extract the 'td element' ( content topContent topContentBox) and put it into a 'div'. The problem I am having is removing a 'div' and 'table' from inside the 'td element'.

below is my php code

```
<?php 
include( 'site/simple_html_dom.php'); 
$html=file_get_html( 'http://achievementhunter.com/blog/');
$html->save('site/ahblog.htm')                      
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="site/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function() {
$('#wrap').click(function (event)
{
event.preventDefault();
});
$('#wrap').load('site/ahblog.htm .content.topContent.topContentBox');
});
</script>
```

below is the 'td element'

```
<div id="wrap">
<td class="content topContent topContentBox" height="100%" width="100%" valign="top">
<div class="titleLine"> <----- I want to remove this one
<div style id="streamDivLeveljournal43125372">
<div style id="streamDivLeveljournal100703120097">
<div style id="streamDivLeveljournal823117600">
<div style id="streamDivLeveljournal43115856">
<div style id="streamDivLeveljournal100703110797">
<table width="100%">...</table> <----- I want to remove this one
</td>
</div>
```

The problem I am having is removing the table as there are multiple tables, and because it doesn't have an 'ID'. If any one coud help me I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Why don't you add an ID?

Comment: Why don't you add an `id` ? Try `$(#wrap table)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".content.topContent.topContentBox").find(".titleLine, table").remove();
```

Should do it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one more snag and that is were to put it so that it works as I have tried a few things and cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: I would put it in the callback function of your load call like `$('#wrap').load('site/ahblog.htm .content.topContent.topContentBox', function() { //remove div and table here });`

Comment: What is it that doesn't work? Can you provide console errors, if there are any?

Comment: I get this `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: That's an issue with syntax, see if you're missing an `}` or `)` somewhere, maybe in the code I wrote on the comments, it was purely pseudo code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43359/discussion-between-loyalar-and-sabre)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('#wrap td').find('.titleLine').remove();
$('#wrap td').find('table').remove();
```